# I'm having trouble with socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm somewhat new to node.js and socket.io which is why I posted this question. Coding off of a step-by-step tutorial video I found on youtube that creates a live chat website, but here is the catch I keep getting is an error that says,  `ReferenceError: io is not defined at /script.js:2:16`. Could someone help me solve this issue?

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Lime</title>
  <script defer src="https://Lime.restivetoo.repl.co:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    #message-container {
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 1200px;
    }

    #message-container div {
      background-color: #CCC;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    #message-container div:nth-child(2n) {
      background-color: #FFF;
    }

    #send-container {
      position: fixed;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: white;
      max-width: 1200px;
      width: 80%;
      display: flex;
    }

    #message-input {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="message-container"></div>
  <form id="send-container">
    <input type="text" id="message-input">
    <button type="submit" id="send-button">Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(8080)

const users = {}

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('new-user', name => {
    users[socket.id] = name
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', name)
  })
  socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', { message: message, name: users[socket.id] })
  })
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id])
    delete users[socket.id]
  })
})
```

**script.js**

```js
const socket = io('https://Lime.restivetoo.repl.co:8080')
const messageContainer = document.getElementById('message-container')
const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')

const name = prompt('What is your name?')
appendMessage('You joined')
socket.emit('new-user', name)

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
  appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`)
})

socket.on('user-connected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} connected`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<script defer src="https://Lime.restivetoo.repl.co:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Excerpt from the docs:

> By default, the Socket.IO server exposes a client bundle at /socket.io/socket.io.js.

[Read more here](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-installation/#standalone-build)